# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'Controller'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I am trying to implement Application Insights logging.

Here is my startup

Under configureservices

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]);
```

Here is my controller

```
    private readonly My_DevContext _context;
    private Task t;
    private readonly IKipReport _kipReport;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public ReportExtractionController(ILogger logger,My_DevContext context, IKipReport kipReport)
    {
        _context = context;
        _kipReport = kipReport;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    // GET: api/<RepprtExtractionController>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        _logger.LogError("Trial");
    }
```

When trying to call the API its saying **500,internal server error**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'Toolset_API.Controllers.ReportExtractionController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method10(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I am working in .NET 5.0

I didnt get what I did wrong.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;
public ReportExtractionController(ILogger<ReportExtractionController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. That worked straight away... I was actually following this which doesnt mentioned it.. https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2020/07/11/6-steps-to-integrate-application-insights-with-net-core-application-hosted-in-azure-app-service/

Comment: Only the constructor parameter needed to change. the field could have remained as `ILogger`

Comment: Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-logs

Comment: I do struggle with this every now and then, too. Is there any explanation on why you have to pass the generic type `ILogger<T>` of the logger instead of just `ILogger`? Found no info on this one yet.

Comment: As noted in the documentation referenced by @Leonardo, the type name of `T` is used used as the logger category name; however, to the @uwe-keim question, this really has more to do with how DI works. Every injected type would get an `ILogger`, but which one? The generic flavor `ILogger<T>`, therefore, has two functions: 1) provide a category, and 2) provide a unique closing type to inject as a dependency

Comment: This worked for my project (.net 5 Azure Function)